# Generalization of the Theorem of Bonnet-Myers

Tags: riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

> Prove the following generalization of the Theorem of Bonnet-Myers: Let $M^n$ be a complete Riemannian manifold. Suppose that there exist constants $a > 0$ and $c \ge 0$ such that for all pairs of points in $M^n$ and for all inimizing geodesics $\gamma(s)$, parametrized by arc length $s$, joining these points, we have
>   $$
> \text{Ric}(\gamma'(s)) \ge a + \frac{df}{ds}, \quad \text{along }\gamma,
> $$
>   where $f$ is a function of $s$, satisfying $|f(s)| \le c$ along $\gamma$. Then $\mathbb M^n$ is compact. Calculate an estimate for the diameter of $M^n$, and observe that if $f \equiv 0$ and $c=0$, we obtain the [Theorem of Bonnet-Myers](http://docdro.id/OwHmANj).

This is Exercise 9.3 of Riemannian Geometry by do Carmo.

I am certain that the argument for this problem is similar, although more sophisticated, to do Carmo's proof of the Theorem of Bonnet-Myers. My approach so far is as follows:
\begin{align}
\frac 12 \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} E_j''(0) &= \int_0^1 \sin^2 (\pi s)((n-1)\pi^2-(n-1)\ell^2 \text{Ric}_{\gamma(s)}(e_n(t))) \, ds \\ 
&\le \int_0^1 \sin^2(\pi s)((n-1)\pi^2-(n-1)\ell^2 \left(a+\frac{df}{ds} \right) \, ds \\
&=(n-1)\left[ \frac{\pi^2-\ell^2 a}2 -\ell^2 \int_0^1 \sin^2 (\pi s) \frac{df}{ds} \, ds \right].
\end{align}
Assuming I'm on the right track (let me know if I'm not), how can I apply $|f(s)| \le c$? What can I do to express $\frac{df}{ds}$ in terms of $f$? Because that would allow me to use the inequality and go from here.

Comment: The condition $\mathrm{Ric} (\gamma'(t), \gamma'(t)) \geq a + f'(t)$ given in the hypothesis is for *normalized* geodesics (parametrized by arclength). If you want to parametrize over $[0,1]$, as doCarmo does in his proof of Myers's Theorem, then the condition becomes $\mathrm{Ric} (\gamma'(t), \gamma'(t)) \geq \ell^2 a + \ell h'(t)$ where $\ell$ is the length of $\gamma$ and $h(t) = f(\ell t)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. The key is to note that you don't have $\frac{df}{ds}$ on it's own, but that you are actually integrating this derivative against $ds$. In particular, we can apply integration by parts to find that 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(\pi s)\frac{df}{ds}~ds = -\pi\int_{0}^{1}\sin(2\pi s)f(s)~ds.$$
So finishing off your estimates we find that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}E_j''(0) & \leq (n-1)\left[\frac{\pi^2-\ell^2a}{2} - \ell^2\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(\pi s)\frac{df}{ds}~ds\right] \\
& = (n-1)\left[\frac{\pi^2-\ell^2a}{2} + \pi\ell^2\int_{0}^{1}\sin(2\pi s)f(s)~ds\right] \\
& \leq (n-1)\left[\frac{\pi^2-\ell^2a}{2} + c\pi\ell^2\int_{0}^{1}|\sin(2\pi s)|~ds\right] \\
& = (n-1)\left[\frac{\pi^2-\ell^2a}{2} + 2c\ell^2\right].
\end{align}
Now you should be able to find a suitable diameter bound which will give you the exact same contradiction that do Carmo gets in his proof of the Bonnet-Myers theorem. Finally, use the Hopf-Rinow theorem to conclude that the manifold is compact.

Comment: I was tempted to say $f(s) \sin(2\pi s) \le c \sin(2\pi s)$, but then I realized that the estimate would not work on $[0,1]$ because $c \sin(2\pi s)$ with $c > 0$ is negative on $(\frac 12,1)$. So the best I can say is $f(s) \sin(2\pi s) \le c |\sin(2\pi s)|$. Is that correct? Nonetheless, this helped me deduce the estimate of the diameter of $M$.

Comment: That is correct. That is why there is an absolute value in the integrand of the second to last step.

Comment: The condition $\mathrm{Ric} (\gamma'(t), \gamma'(t)) \geq a + f'(t)$ given in the hypothesis is for *normalized* geodesics (parametrized by arclength). If you want to parametrize over $[0,1]$, as doCarmo does in his proof of Myers's Theorem, then the condition becomes $\mathrm{Ric} (\gamma'(t), \gamma'(t)) \geq \ell^2 a + \ell h'(t)$ where $\ell$ is the length of $\gamma$ and $h(t) = f(\ell t)$.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Spiro Karigiannis that the answer by Yousuf Soliman had ignored that the condition of Ricci curvature  is for normalized geodesics. The final estimate should be like
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}E_j''(0)≤k_1(\pi^2-l^2a)+k_2lc
$$
where $k_1,k_2$ are constants，$l$ is the length. When $l$ is large enough the right side is always less than $0$ (no matter how large $c$ is) and then we can argue like do Carmo in his proof of the Bonnet-Myers theorem to get contradiction.

To get this estimate we first deduce from $\text{Ric}(\gamma'(s)) \ge a + \frac{df}{ds}$ that $\text{Ric}(\tilde\gamma'(t)/l) \ge a + \frac{1}{l}\frac{dg}{dt}$，where $\tilde\gamma(t)=\gamma(lt)$ and  $g(t)=f(lt)$. Use this new inequality we can see in the final estimate the second term should be $k_2lc$ not $k_2l^2c$.